# How to restore empty simulators list in Xcode

Tags: xcode, xcode10.3

I recently updated to Xcode 10.3 and now the list of simulators is empty.

How do I get the full list of simulators restored?

Answer (score 0):

I rebooted my computer and when I re-opened my Xcode project, the full simulators list was restored.